# PS- to-PK converter has stopped working

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex

I compile the latex file using miktex, during the preview in `yap` it shows 
`PS- to-PK converter has stopped working` error. There is no problem during compilation. Please suggest me the correct.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to preview DVI files?

Comment: @egreg Without `DVI` how can i create `PS` or `PDF`? so DVI preview is importent.

Comment: If you don't need PS, but only PDF, then DVI is not required, as `pdflatex` directly outputs PDF.

Comment: No I need PS. so i dont want the `pdflatex`

Comment: With given information noone can help you in the moment. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.